Deriving a column using the previous row's value of the column itself?



operation
txn_quantity
cumulative_quantity
txn_amount
cost_of_purchase
sell_ratio
NET_COST




buy
250
250
5000
5000
0
0


sell
100
150
3000
0
0.4
0


buy
150
300
1500
1500
0
0


sell
225
75
4000
0
0.75
0



Above I have a simulated transaction table. My ultimate goal is to derive the average cost for each row, and the most accurate way to get this is (net cost / cumulative quantity).
In order to calculate net cost, I need to do a conditional running sum:

If it's a buy, add cost_of_purchase
If it's a sell, minus (previous row net cost * sell ratio)

Below is the expected output of NET_COST, which then can be used to derive AVERAGE_COST



operation
txn_quantity
cumulative_quantity
txn_amount
cost_of_purchase
sell_ratio
NET_COST
AVERAGE_COST




buy
250
250
5000
5000
0
5000
20


sell
100
150
3000
0
0.4
3000
20


buy
150
300
1500
1500
0
4500
15


sell
225
75
4000
0
0.75
1125
15



For further clarity, here's what's happening in each cell for NET_COST



NET_COST




0 + 5000


5000 - (5000 * 0.4)


3000 + 1500


4500 - (4500 * 0.75)



Is this achievable in SQL (Impala / Hive)?

What are the rows to be ordered in?

In SQL Server exists LAG function that allow accesses data from a previous row in the same result set without the use of a self-join. Without a sample data set we don't know how you are ordering your results, this is needed to provide an OVER clause in the LAG function to know which is the previuos row. With LAG you can retrieve the previuos NET COST then with CASE you must calculate the NET COST based on your condition on the operation type.

@tinazmu assume there's a column to indicate the sequence

@antonio_mg based on my understanding, LAG allows you to retrieve the previous value of another column, not the column you're computing

If they support recursive queries :
with cte(id, operation, cost_of_purchase, sell_ratio, net_cost) as (
    select d.*, 
        case operation when 'buy' then cost_of_purchase 
            else 0 end
    from data d where id = 1
    
    union all
    
    select d.id, d.operation, d.cost_of_purchase, d.sell_ratio,
        case d.operation when 'buy' then 
            c.net_cost + d.cost_of_purchase
            else c.net_cost - c.net_cost * d.sell_ratio
        end
    from cte c
    join data d on c.id + 1 = d.id
)
select * from cte ;

If they support MODEL clause:
select * from data
model
    dimension by (id)
    measures( operation as operation, cost_of_purchase as cost_of_purchase, sell_ratio as sell_ratio, 0 as net_cost )
    rules 
    (
        net_cost[any] = case operation[cv()] when 'buy' 
                            then nvl(net_cost[cv()-1],0) + cost_of_purchase[cv()]
                            else nvl(net_cost[cv()-1],0) - nvl(net_cost[cv()-1],0) * sell_ratio[cv()]
                        end
    )
;

